# ubuntu 16.04 32bit boot crash when memory is 4GB on Xen

Tags: boot, 16.04, crash, xen

I've install ubuntu 16.04 32bit on Xen platform, it boot OK when memory is less than 4GB, but when i set the memory to 4GB, it will crash when the system is booting.

The call trace is like:

```
[    2.796566] init[1]: segfault at b74d0420 ip b74d0420 sp bfdecdfc error 7 in libc-2.23.so[b7459000+1af000]
[    2.809698] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x0000000b
[    2.809698] 
[    2.812634] CPU: 1 PID: 1 Comm: init Not tainted 4.4.0-21-generic #37-Ubuntu
[    2.812634] Hardware name: Xen HVM domU, BIOS Unknown 07/18/2016
[    2.812634]  c1abd967 f7a742e8 00000086 f3e03df0 c139d21f f3e57ca0 f3e48000 f3e03e08
[    2.812634]  c116dc50 f3e48000 f3e57ca0 f3e48000 f3e48000 f3e03e54 c1071a94 c19b41f0
[    2.812634]  0000000b f3eb500c f3e48440 f3e03e2c f3e48000 00000001 00000000 c1ad8a00
[    2.812634] Call Trace:
[    2.812634]  [<c139d21f>] dump_stack+0x58/0x79
[    2.812634]  [<c116dc50>] panic+0x81/0x1af
[    2.812634]  [<c1071a94>] do_exit+0xa04/0xa10
[    2.812634]  [<c1071b17>] do_group_exit+0x37/0x90
[    2.812634]  [<c107d477>] get_signal+0x257/0x5f0
[    2.812634]  [<c105cf49>] ? force_sig_info_fault.constprop.23+0x79/0xa0
[    2.812634]  [<c10298d9>] do_signal+0x29/0x5d0
[    2.812634]  [<c1175247>] ? __free_pages+0x27/0x30
[    2.812634]  [<c10c61f1>] ? vprintk_default+0x41/0x60
[    2.812634]  [<c105d40a>] ? bad_area_access_error+0x3a/0x50
[    2.812634]  [<c105dba7>] ? __do_page_fault+0x247/0x470
[    2.812634]  [<c10030d4>] exit_to_usermode_loop+0x94/0xe0
[    2.812634]  [<c105ddd0>] ? __do_page_fault+0x470/0x470
[    2.812634]  [<c10037a8>] prepare_exit_to_usermode+0x18/0x20
[    2.812634]  [<c17a6c8e>] resume_userspace+0xe/0x14
[    2.812634] Kernel Offset: disabled
```

The call trace is not always like this, but they all have resume_userspace call.
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I also tried ubuntu 16.04.1 and it worked fine with 4GB RAM